# How to add word boundaries to a variable in regex (Python)

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a word that I'm trying to match from a .txt file

`word = "hello"`

How do I add word boundaries (\b) on both ends so I can just match the exact word.
So without the variable it'll look like this:

`x = re.search(r'\bhello\b', txt)`

but since I'm taking the string as an input, I want it to add the boundaries to my variable instead.

Comment: `+` operator does also string concatenation. A regex search pattern is just a string.

Comment: I wish this were true. Unfortunately it does not pan out as such.